# Filter array of object with conditional statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have JavaScript object array with the following structure:

> ```
> const fruits =       [{
>                         "id": "1",
>                         "title": "Banana",
>                         "description": "1 Minute"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "2",
>                         "title": "Apple",
>                         "description": "2 - 3 Days"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "3",
>                         "title": "Manggo",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "4",
>                         "title": "Orange",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "5",
>                         "title": "Grape blue",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "6",
>                         "title": "Grape red",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     }]
> ```

I want to extract object which has `description` = "10 - 20 Days" and `title` **not contains** "Grape"

Then my expected should be

> ```
>                     {
>                         "id": "3",
>                         "title": "Manggo",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "4",
>                         "title": "Orange",
>                         "description": "10 - 20 Days"
>                     }
> ```

Comment: This what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @Rama `fruits.filter(fruit => (fruit.description === "10 - 20 Days" && !fruit.title.includes('Grape')))`  this will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to do by using [`Array.protoype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Within the `filter` callback, you can use [`String.protoype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if the title includes `"grapes"`:

```js
const fruits = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Banana",
    "description": "1 Minute"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Apple",
    "description": "2 - 3 Days"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Manggo",
    "description": "10 - 20 Days"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Orange",
    "description": "10 - 20 Days"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "title": "Grape blue",
    "description": "10 - 20 Days"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "title": "Grape red",
    "description": "10 - 20 Days"
  }
];

const filteredFruits = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  if (!fruit.title.toLowerCase().includes("grape")) {
    if (fruit.description === "10 - 20 Days") {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
});

console.dir(filteredFruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use filter like this

```
const fruits =       [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "title": "Banana",
                        "description": "1 Minute"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "title": "Apple",
                        "description": "2 - 3 Days"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "title": "Manggo",
                        "description": "10 - 20 Days"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "title": "Orange",
                        "description": "10 - 20 Days"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5",
                        "title": "Grape blue",
                        "description": "10 - 20 Days"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "title": "Grape red",
                        "description": "10 - 20 Days"
                    }]

const res = fruits.filter(val=> !val.title.includes('Grape') && val.description.includes('10 - 20 Days'))

console.log(res)
```