# How to remove a object from a array of object based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, foreach

I have array of objects like this:

```
data = [
 {
   "name":"abc",
   "email":"abc@gmail.com"
 },
 {
   "name": "bcd",
   "email": "bcd@gmail.com",
   "info":[
     {
        "email": "bcd@gmail.com",
        "count":5
     }
     ]
 },
 {
    "name": "hfv",
    "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
    "info":[
      {
      "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
      "count":5
      },
      {
        "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
        "count":7
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I want to to change `data` in such a way that only objects that have `count>1` should exist

so the output should like this:

```
[{
   "name": "bcd",
   "email": "bcd@gmail.com",
   "info":[
     {
        "email": "bcd@gmail.com",
        "count":5
     }
     ]
 },
 {
    "name": "hfv",
    "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
    "info":[
      {
      "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
      "count":5
      },
      {
        "email": "hfv@gmail.com",
        "count":7
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

the `data` array should look like this, how I can I loop through this array of objects and remove objects that have count<=1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of object with conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67590053/filter-array-of-object-with-conditional-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve it

`const result = data.filter(obj => obj.info && obj.info.filter(info => info.count > 1).length > 0)`

You may need to filter info objects as well... depends of your need. But you have everything you need here.

Comment: Good answer here, but could be slightly wrong. The wording of the question is slightly unclear, does the OP want ALL parent objects, but only show there `items` if the item count if greater than one, or does the OP want to filter out the parent objects too? If it's the first, then the first filter should be replaced with a map instead.

Comment: You can slightly improve solution:  `data.filter(obj => obj.info?.some(({ count }) => count > 1))`